# Getters returning null

Tags: java, android, null, encapsulation

I know why my problem is occurring but i'm unsure on how to deal with it.

So I have 3 classes, 1 of these holds my getters & setters. In one class I am setting the values, in the other I am getting the values. When I get the values they are returned null. This is obviously because the two instances of the getter/setter object I created in the classes are separate from one another. What i'm trying to find out is how I can set the values in one class and get them in another without having two separate instances of the getter/setter class. My wording is terrible so here's a more visual explanation:

**Class 1**

```
Encapsulation encap = new Encapsulation();
encap.setValue(10);
```

**Class 2**

```
Encapsulation encap = new Encapsulation();
encap.getValue(); //I want this to return 10
```

**Class 3 (Encapsulation)**

```
private int value;

public void setValue(int value){
    this.value = value;
}

public int getValue(){
    return value
}
```

Comment: Why creating new object in Class 2.

Comment: you should create a single class. So that you can use the values in any calss

Comment: a function returning an `int` can't return `null`

Comment: As pointed you are creating new Object again, Each object has its own memory area. if you want to pass object to other activity then pass using Bundle mechanism of android. follow this http://hmkcode.com/android-passing-java-object-another-activity/

Comment: Use single instance and get value

Comment: Can someone check my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Class2, you are creating a new instance of class Encapsulation. (Notice new Encapsulation()). So obviously, that won't hold the values.

Instead, I would suggest you two solutions:

**First:**

Save that object in an Application class as you are working on Android application.

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {
    public Encapsulation tempClass;
    public TestApplication () {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public Encapsulation getTempClass() {
        return tempClass;
    }

    public void setTempClass(Encapsulation tempClass) {
        this.tempClass  = tempClass;
    }
}
```

Now in your Activity:

```
//after setContentView
testAppObj = (TestApplication) getApplication();
testAppObj.setTempClass(myTempClassObj);

//retrieve as:
Encapsulation obj = testAppObj.getTempClass();
```

You must register your Application class in your manifest file just like you register your activities:

```
<application
        android:name="com.pkg.test.TestApplication " />
```

**Second:**

Keep object encap as static in Class1. So you can access it from calss2. (I don't prefer static.)

Hope it helps.

Comment: You see these words "In Class2, you are creating a new instance of class Encapsulation. (Notice new Encapsulation()). So obviously, that won't hold the values." They are heavenly. i couldnt proceed for like a month until i saw these heavenly words. Thank You for the wisdom, MY HERO>>>:)

Answer (score 3):

Make value static, it will keep the same value across all `Encapsulation` instances

```
private static int value;

public void setValue(int aValue){
    value = aValue;
}

public int getValue(){
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare an object of the Encapsulation class once,and use the same instance to call the getter and setter.

Like this:

```
Encapsulation encap = new Encapsulation();
encap.setValue(10);
encap.getValue();
```

It works.